# What's the best way to restore a keyPair from a string, extracted with secretKey.toString()?

Tags: web3.js

Say I have a `secretKeyString` extracted from a keyPair using `keyPair.secretKey.toString();`

I know I can restore a `keyPair` from the string with:

```
const secretKeyStringToKeypair = (secretKeyString: string) => {
  const secretKeyArray = secretKeyString.split(",").map(Number);
  const secretKey = Uint8Array.from(secretKeyArray);
  const keyPair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);
  return keyPair;
};
```

Which works, I can do:

```
expect(keyPair2.secretKey.toString()).toEqual(
  keyPair.secretKey.toString()
);
```

**But is there a better way of doing this?** Mapping the string into an array using string methods seems a bit suboptimal, and I'm surprised there's not something built in to `@solana/web3.js`. I had a peek in the [Solana Cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-restore-a-keypair-from-a-secret) and couldn't find anything on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question: this works, but **it's better to simply avoid `keyPair.secretKey.toString()`**. Instead save the base58 encoded value of the secretKey:

```
export const secretKeyToHex = (secretKey: Uint8Array) => {
  return base58.encode(secretKey);
};
```

And then import that:

```
export const getKeypairFromString = (secretKeyString: string) => {
  let decodedSecretKey: Uint8Array;
  try {
    decodedSecretKey = base58.decode(secretKeyString);
  } catch (throwObject) {
    throw new Error("Invalid secret key! See README.md");
  }
  return Keypair.fromSecretKey(decodedSecretKey);
};
```